# How do I backup Oracle database (about 1TB size) in VMware without using RMAN?

Tags: oracle, backup, vmware

It's been a while since I am struggling to find a backup solution for cold backup of Oracle database on Linux in VMware. I am obviously not looking for entire vm image backup.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  10g+ means that data pump might be an option: http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/utilities/index.html

Comment: datapump is not really a backup in oracle's terminology : no roll forward.

Answer (score 2):

You want a cold backup or a hot backup ? Are you using ARCHIVELOG mode or not ? Though, I really do not recommend not using RMAN, that sounds like a crazy thing to me ;)

Comment: agree - what is the reason for wanting a cold backup?  Since Oracle will be touching all of its files during normal operation, you'll be backing up 1TB each time you want a restore point.  You'll also lose the ability to restore to any state between the cold backups.

Answer (score 1):

You may get a better answer on ServerFault.
What is the hardware for the underlying storage. A sophisticated RAID setup may allow you to split off a mirror for backup which could minimise the downtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use rman ( for whatever reason ). Then your only option is

1. Shutdown database.
2. Backup all oracle files ( data files, control files, etc ) using any number of file backup solutions.
3. Startup database.

Step two is obviously the difficult part.. but this can't really be answered without better knowledge of what hardware your disks are running on.

Given the size of the database, and assuming that you want to minimize downtime, then I'd hope you are running on some kind of filesystem which allows you to take a snapshot, which can then be moved offsite.